# how to perform Rank query in Django

Tags: sql, django, dense-rank, ranking-functions

I am stuck at this point and this query seems a bit tricky to me
so basically i am getting data from devices in periodic ***intervals*** 'lets say 3 hours'

But every device is sending data twice on every interval(3 hours), i am required to extract device data that is send last(in intervals)

```
"date": "2021-11-28",
        "time": "12 : 35",
        "meter": "70F8E7FFFE10C495",
       
        "dr": 3,
        "date_received": "2021-11-28T18:05:20.473430+05:30",
       
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "2021-11-28",
        "time": "12 : 37",
        "meter": "70F8E7FFFE10C459",
       
        "date_received": "2021-11-28T18:07:09.980403+05:30",
   
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": "2021-11-28",
        "time": "12 : 37",
        "meter": "70F8E7FFFE10C459", <---- this occurrence only
       
        "dr": 3,
        "date_received": "2021-11-28T18:07:11.533388+05:30",
      
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "date": "2021-11-28",
        "time": "12 : 50",
        "meter": "70F8E7FFFE10C463",
       
        "date_received": "2021-11-28T18:20:44.197284+05:30",
       
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "date": "2021-11-28",
        "time": "12 : 56",
        "meter": "70F8E7FFFE10C47D",
     
        "date_received": "2021-11-28T18:26:43.221316+05:30",
      
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "date": "2021-11-28",
        "time": "12 : 56",
        "meter": "70F8E7FFFE10C47D",   <---- only want to get this occurrence in similar manner
      
        "date_received": "2021-11-28T18:26:44.925292+05:30",
     
    },
```

So if `device : 70F8E7FFFE10C459` sends data twice i want to retrieve only last sent data , and this needs obj in queryset , i was told about `RANK` concept don't understand how to apply that here

*In general i just want to know the query to apply, raw query will also work*

```
class MeterData(models.Model):
    meter = models.ForeignKey('dashboard.Meter',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    battery  = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)
    crc_status = models.CharField(max_length=43,null=True,blank=True)
    Pulse_count = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=False)
    status_data = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    status_magnet_temper = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    meter_reading = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    status_switch_temper = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status_voltage_level = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    uplink_type = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    confirmed_uplink = models.BooleanField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    tx_info_frequency = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    dr = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    date_received = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
```

Comment: Please put your query and the Model in the question.

Comment: which query ? how to query it that is the question @ahmadgh74

Comment: Sorry. I mean put your model.

Comment: It seems you want to order your data by `date_recieved` and `distinct` your data based on `device id` (maybe customer). let me know If I'm wrong or not.

Comment: distinct will remove save device id's ? i want distinction to happen only on intervals

Comment: No, it will not remove anything. It only makes your result unique based on a column.

Comment: can u post relevant `query `

Answer (score 0):

**It doesn't work on Sqlite**

I think the following query is the correct answer.

```py
MeterData.objects.filter(put_your_filters_here).order_by('-date_received').distinct('customer_id')
```

For SQLite DB use the below query:

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef


distinct_subquery = Subquery(MeterData.objects.filter(put_your_filters_here, customer_id=OuterRef('customer_id')).order_by('-date_received').values('id')[:1])

MeterData.objects.filter(put_your_filters_here, id__in=distinct_subquery).order_by('-date_received')
```

if it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: it should work in sqlite

Comment: I just updated it.